# htaccess rewrite URL to SEO friendly

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is this possible to have URL's like this
`Mysite.com/somefile.php?cat=someparameter` to `Mysite.com/someparameter`

I'm new to htaccess.

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /somefile.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /somefile.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for quick reply :-)
What it should be if `Mysite.com/somefile.php?cat=someparameter&subcat=subcategory` ??

Comment: ok see the edit now. You can have pretty URL for that `/someparameter/subcategory`

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out for you.